# Notice: Undefined variable: i

Tags: variables, undefined

Welcome

I have some problem wits code. Could u help me? i search for the Ethernet but i don't found same example. Below error code:

Notice: Undefined variable: i in /reklamacje/index.php on line 72

The problem / error line - $i=$i+1;

I know that i need some isset option.. or something else ?

More code:

```
foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {
$m=$i%2; // required for alternate color of rows matching to style class 
$i=$i+1;   //  increment for alternate color of rows
echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$row['od_firma']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['nr_narzedzia']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['nr_faktury']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['data_przyjecia']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['data_wyslania']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['opis_rek']."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$row['kto_rozpatrzyl']."</td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"index.php?a=dodaj&amp;id={$row['id']}\">Dodaj</a></td>";
        echo "<td><a href=\"index.php?a=edit&amp;id={$row['id']}\">Edytuj</a></td>";
                echo "<td><a href=\"index.php?a=del&amp;id={$row['id']}\">Usuń</a></td>";

        echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table><br><br>";
////////////////////////////// End of displaying the table with records ////////////////////////

/////////////////////////////// 
if($nume > $limit ){ // Let us display bottom links if sufficient records are there for paging

/////////////// Start the bottom links with Prev and next link with page numbers /////////////////
echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";
//// if our variable $back is equal to 0 or more then only we will display the link to move back ////////
if($back >=0) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
} 
//////////////// Let us display the page links at  center. We will not display the current page as a link ///////////
echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
$i=0;
$l=1;
for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
if($i <> $eu){
echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$l</font></a> ";
}
else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$l</font>";}        /// Current page is not displayed as link and given font color red
$l=$l+1;
}


echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";
///////////// If we are not in the last page then Next link will be displayed. Here we check that /////
if($this1 < $nume) { 
print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
echo "</td></tr></table>";

// end of if checking sufficient records are there to display bottom navigational link. 
}
```

How to change it ?

Greeting for all help information.

Comment: Hint: Place $i=0; above foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) loop.

Comment: Working !!! Thank You!